# How to combine two sub queries using CASE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, sum, pivot, cout

I have 2 sub queries

```
SELECT 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE 
    DAYS_AGED >= 792
```

and

```
SELECT 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE 
    DAYS_AGED < 792
```

The problem is I want to combine them using simple case statement as:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN DAYS_AGED >= 792 
          THEN SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
       WHEN DAYS_AGED < 792 
          THEN SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
    END
FROM 
    TABLE_A
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 127
> Column 'TABLE_A.DAYS_AGED' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I might want to add I can combine them using UNION or CTE, this works

```
SELECT 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE 
    DAYS_AGED >= 792
UNION
SELECT 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT), 
    SUM(QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE) / SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE 
    DAYS_AGED < 792
```

Is there a way to collate these 2 sub queries using CASE statement, is there a possibility to do so

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `CASE` expression *within* the aggregate functions:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED >= 792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT*PRICE END) amount1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED >= 792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT END) qty_bought1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED >= 792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE END) 
        / SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED >= 792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT END) avg1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED <  792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT*PRICE END) amount2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED <  792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT END) qty_bought2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED <  792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT * PRICE END) 
        / SUM(CASE WHEN DAYS_AGED <  792 THEN QTY_BOUGHT END) avg2
FROM TABLE_A
```

Comment: is there a possibility to do this using IF.. ELSE, I'm just curious if it can be done

IF DAYS_AGED >= 792
SELECT SUM(QTY_BOUGHT*PRICE) , SUM(QTY_BOUGHT), SUM(QTY_BOUGHT*PRICE)/SUM(QTY_BOUGHT)
FROM TABLE_A

something in these lines ...

Comment: `IF...ELSE` is a logical flow operator, @Sree , not a function. It can't be used within a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `IIF` could be used  instead of `CASE`... but behind the scenes it is still `CASE` expression.